# How to add customized bones with Auto Rig Pro Plugin?

Tags: bones, auto-rig-pro

I am modeling a vrchat character with Auto Rig Pro Plugin and I trying to add some bones to character such as hair, eyes, clothes, etc.

I used “Add Limb -> Chain: Bendy Bones” to added hair bones and pressed “SetCustomBones”. After this, I can expectly see the bending effect when I move the controller in Blender.

[image]
[image]

BUT after I imported into Unity FBX and tried to bend it, the effects of bones is no more exist.
Other than that the Hair Mesh has no vertex group come up with that bone.

[image]

I’m sure that before I export, the Mesh has the Vertex Group that mesh could bend properly, But after exported those are all gone, What’s causing it?

Or, It’s there any possible that I did wrong with the hair modeling from the beginning?
If I wanna make hair model with Auto Rig Pro Plugin and bones for Clothes, what should I do?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures might apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Custom bones in Auto Rig Pro aren't exported by default: you have to tell it explicitly, or use the appropriate naming conventions, see ARP Manual for details: http://lucky3d.fr/auto-rig-pro/doc/ge_export_doc.html.

Comment: I already used 'SetCustomBones' as the manual told, and the bones can be exported. But the vertices are still not bound to the bones in fbx.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it was a bones layer issue (old thread but it still appear as pertinent in Google).

Select your added bones, Press M to Change Bone Layer, and be sure that the blue square (current layer) is the second at the bottom left. Could have been that.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Custom bones are designated with a "cc_" prefix in properies.
http://lucky3d.fr/auto-rig-pro/doc/ge_export_doc.html